# Problem starting Mac Mail on Big Sur

Tags: mail.app

I have just bought a new Mac Mini (M1) with Big Sur.
When I start Mail I get a screen headed "Message Import" , "Welcome to Mail". I have 2 options Continue to import messages or Cancel to import later.

If I select either option Mail closes down.

Any ideas please.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by re-installing clean copy of Big Sur